# how to get the value from button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some buttons which are created dynamically based on the number of phone numbers present.Suppose I have 3 names in DB so there will be three buttons.So when I click on the 1st button then it should give the value of first button,if 2nd is clicked then 2nd button value should display.This is simple [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/45FxE/1/) which describes about my requirement.I thought of assigning the each button a different id which should be the phone number.In the jsfiddle when i am clicking on a particular button then alert pops but it does not give any value.

i did like this

```
$('.btn').click(function(){ 
var number1 = $('#s2').val();
alert(number1);
});
```

Comment: Which value are you trying to retrieve? Your button doesn't have any `value` attribute.

Comment: @Alvaro can I get the ID of each button

Comment: To get the `id` you should do:  `var number1 = $('#s2').attr('id');`

Comment: @Alvaro thanks you should post it as answer so that i can upvote.Well in the jsfiddle I have textfield which accepts number.So if i click button1 then s1 will be displayed in the textfield,if button2 then s2 so that user will not be required to type the number.Can you please help me in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use event delegation using [jQuery's `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). From its documentation:

> When a selector is provided, the event handler is referred to as delegated. The handler is not called when the event occurs directly on the bound element, but only for descendants (inner elements) that match the selector. jQuery bubbles the event from the event target up to the element where the handler is attached (i.e., innermost to outermost element) and runs the handler for any elements along that path matching the selector.

In your case, you'll need to delegate the `.btn` click event to an ancestor which exists prior to that element being dynamically added to the page:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    var number1 = $('#s2').val();
    alert(number1);
});
```

The closer you get to the `.btn` element, the better, so unless your document's `body` is the nearest non-dynamic ancestor then you'll want to change this to something a bit closer.

---

**Edit:** Further question in comments:

> can I get the ID of each button

To get the `id` of each button, simply use `this.id`:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});
```

---

**Edit 2:** Further question in comments

> So as I said,ID are numbers.So if i click button1 then it will print s1 in the inputfield.Can you please tell me how to do?

As your `input` has an `id` of "number", you can simply use jQuery's `.val()` method to set the value of the `input` to the `id` of the clicked button:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
    $('#number').val(this.id);
});
```

[**Working JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/45FxE/2/).

Comment: Not working this way too,alert is popping up but does not contain any values

Comment: Does your element with `id` "s2" have a value?

Comment: thanks $('body').on('click', '.btn', function() {
    var id = this.id;
    alert(id);
});

Comment: No problem! :) I've made a working JSFiddle demo showing this code in action too: http://jsfiddle.net/cJej7/

Comment: So as I said,ID are numbers.So if i click button1 then it will print s1 in the inputfield.Can you please tell me how to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function(){ 
   alert($(this).val()); 
});
```

Should work. The "on" is a way of working with dynamically placed elements.

Comment: If you're wanting to get the ID of the button change "alert($(this).val());" to "alert($(this).attr('id'));"

Comment: As you saw in my jsfiddle there is one inputfield which accepts number.So if i click button1 then in the inputfield s1 will be displayed,similarily if buttton2 then s2 will be displayed.Do you know how to do this

Comment: your answer is useful +1

Answer (score 1):

Put value attribute in button input

```
  <button type="button" class="btn" value="test2" >test</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" value="test1" id="s1">test</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" value="test" id="s2">test</button>
```

And then use script

```
 $('.btn').on('click', function() {
       var number = $('#s2').val();//get value

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the id of the clicked button you should use `attr`:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){ 
   var number1 = $('#s2').attr('id');
   alert(number1);
});
```